# Definition of Fractional Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

I'm confused with the definition of fractional ideals.

In "Advanced Modern Algebra by Rotman" the definition is as follows: If $R$ is a domain with $F$ = Frac$(R)$, then a fractional ideal is a finitely
generated nonzero $R$-submodule of $F$.

However, in other sources they define it as: Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $F$ be its field of fractions. A fractional ideal of R is an $R$-submodule $I$ of $F$ such that there exists a non-zero $r\in R$ such that $rI \subset R$.

So in the second definition, a fractional ideal is not necessarily finitely generated module. For example, if $R$ is noetherian then it is finitely generated.

Which one is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by a definition being "correct"?

Comment: These definitions are different. Why don't we have one definition and what's the advantage of one to other?

Comment: Then that's what you should have asked, not "which one is correct?"